# Can't get cookies from Indy TIdCookieManager

Tags: delphi, cookies, indy, delphi-xe7, indy10

I have Indy 10.6, Windows 10, and Delphi XE7.

In a response to an HTTPS `GET` request, the `CookieManager` states there are no cookies, but an HTTP Analyzer shows that there is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Jul 2018 10:47:22 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: No-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=vqf9bFgB0wp1vyznZTQ2TLGzpQbpYQTgnwqhtvQpl2D0JdsrpH8G!-32035106!wls-baap401.test.vocalink.co.uk!13129!13109; path=/; HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 162
```

My code is:

```
html := IdHTTP1.Get(Login);

Cookies := IdCookieManager1.CookieCollection.LockCookieList(caRead);
  try
    for I := 0 to Cookies.Count-1 do
    begin
      Cookie := Cookies[I];
      // save Cookie as needed...
    end;
  finally
    IdCookieManager1.CookieCollection.UnlockCookieList(caRead);
  end;
```

But `Cookies.Count` is 0.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Sorted. As a newbie to Indy I forgot to connect the cookie manager to idHTTP !
Now the code works as it should.

Comment: FYI, you could replace `IdCookieManager1` with `IdHTTP1.CookieManager` in your loop code, and then you can optionally remove `IdCookieManager1` from your project as `TIdHTTP` creates its own `CookieManager` internally if you don't assign one explicitly and `AllowCookies` is true.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. I have changed the code as suggested, which is cleaner and obviously works. Until I started this project I did not realise that there can be multiple cookies!

```
html := IdHTTP1.get(login);

cookies := IdHTTP1.CookieManager.CookieCollection.LockCookieList(caRead);
try
  for J := 0 to cookies.count - 1 do
  begin
    cookie := cookies[J];
    // save Cookie as needed...
    CookieValue := cookie.CookieText;
  end;
finally
  IdHTTP1.CookieManager.CookieCollection.UnlockCookieList(caRead);
end ;
```

Regards, Ian